# OkHttp: A simple GET request: response.body().string() returns unreadable escaped unicode symbols inside json can't convert to gson

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, gson, okhttp

When sending a request in Postman, I get this output:

```
{
    "valid": false,
    "reason": "taken",
    "msg": "Username has already been taken",
    "desc": "That username has been taken. Please choose another."
}
```

However when doing it using `okhttp`, I get encoding problems and can't convert the resulting json string to a Java object using `gson`.

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TwitterChecker checker = new TwitterChecker();
        TwitterJson twitterJson = checker.checkUsername("dogster");
        System.out.println(twitterJson.getValid());  //NPE
        System.out.println(twitterJson.getReason());
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public TwitterJson checkUsername(String username) throws Exception  {
        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://twitter.com/users/username_available").newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username", username);
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")

                .build();


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        Response response = call.execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(
                response.body().string(), new TypeToken<TwitterJson>() {
                }.getType());

    }
```

Which prints this:

```
{"valid":false,"reason":"taken","msg":"\u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u043c\u044f \u0443\u0436\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u043d\u044f\u0442\u043e","desc":"\u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u043c\u044f \u0443\u0436\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u043d\u044f\u0442\u043e. \u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u0432\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043e\u0435."}
```

and then throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to access a `twitterJson`. Debugger shows that object as being `null`.

**TwitterJson**:

```
@Generated("net.hexar.json2pojo")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class TwitterJson {
    @Expose
    private String desc;
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @Expose
    private String reason;
    @Expose
    private Boolean valid;

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public Boolean getValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    ...
```

How can I fix the encoding issues with okhttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the response object can be consumed only once. OKHTTP says that in their [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/). After the execute is invoked, you are calling the response object twice. Store the result of response.body().string() to a variable and then do the convert into GSON.

If I were to use a hello world example...

```
private void testOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("https://www.google.com")
          .build();
      Call call = httpClient.newCall(request);
      Response response = call.execute();
      System.out.println("First time " + response.body().string()); // I get the response
      System.out.println("Second time " + response.body().string()); // This will be empty
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The reason it is empty the second time is because the response object can be consumed only once. So you either

Return the response as it is. Do not do a sysOut

```
System.out.println(response.body().string()); // Instead of doing a sysOut return the value.
```

Or

Store the value of the response to a JSON then convert it to GSON and then return the value.

**EDIT**: Concerning Unicode characters. It turned out since my location is not an English-speaking country, the json i was accepting was not in English as well. I added this header:

```
.addHeader("Accept-Language", Locale.US.getLanguage())
```

to the request to fix that.